# multiple animations on one div

Tags: jquery, image

So I have a background image and a masked image over top.  I have a set of four buttons that I want to move the top image to different locations when they are clicked.  I have been testing out the jquery animate function but I cant return the image back to its original state afterwards, I know this is probably the wrong way but this is what I have so far for my jquery:

```
<script>

$("#right").click(function() {
$("#content").animate(
        {"left": "+=200px"},
        "slow");
});
$("#left").click(function() {
$("#content").animate(
        {"left": "-=200px"},
        "slow");
});

$("#farRight").click(function() {
$("#content").animate(
        {"left": "+=400px"},
        "slow");
});


</script>
```

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should write a CSS class with the appropriate transition, and add and remove that. That takes care of the animation, and is easy to toggle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to store the original location, so you can return to it. I'd use jQuery's `data` method to do this:

```
$("#content").data("originalPosition", $("#content").position());

$("#return").click(function() {
    $("#content").animate({
        "left": $("#content").data("originalPosition").left
    }, "slow");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ryanbrill/KPLTy/

Comment: yes absolutely, i don't mean to be over zealous especially at my level of javascript but is there a way of having each div store the original location of the content so that each time the left, right, farRight div is clicked it animates in relation to the contents original starting position?

Comment: Sure - you can just reset the left position before you run the animation. See this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ryanbrill/KPLTy/1/

Comment: great! thanks Ryan, I tried to vote on your answer but im new to this so I guess I need to build my reputation points before I have that access, ill see what I can do about that - thanks again!